# indexing duplicated cases of a data frame in R

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, multiple-columns

to create a report I have to rearrange my data.frame.

It is:

```
     id       date  kind datn 
AE00049 1999-03-01 train    2 
AE00049 1999-03-01   bus    2 
AE00049 2009-05-01 train    1 
AE00052 1997-07-15   bus    1 
AE00066 2005-09-01  tram    1 
AE0007X 2009-07-01   bus    2 
AE0007X 2009-07-01 train    2 
AE00186 2002-11-01   bus    3 
AE00186 2002-11-01 train    3 
AE00186 2002-11-01  tram    3
```

My aim is to give a new indexnumber to the lines with the same ID and date, like this:

```
     id      date  kind datn datnno
AE00049 1999-03-01 train    2      1
AE00049 1999-03-01   bus    2      2
AE00049 2009-05-01 train    1      1
AE00052 1997-07-15   bus    1      1
AE00066 2005-09-01  tram    1      1
AE0007X 2009-07-01   bus    2      1
AE0007X 2009-07-01 train    2      2
AE00186 2002-11-01   bus    3      1
AE00186 2002-11-01 train    3      2
AE00186 2002-11-01  tram    3      3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The new answer is more code saving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `ave` to create a sequence column using 'id' and 'date' as grouping variables.

```
 df1$datnno <- with(df1, ave(seq_along(id), id, date, FUN=seq_along))
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I tried "ave", but not with "with". "With" seems to be helpful for other problems as well. Best wishes!

Comment: I've done the click on the tickmark. Thanks for this hint!

Comment: I've one more question: It seems to be, that the code doesn't work proberly with NAs. How can I remove NA within this code?

Comment: @VolkerHolzendorf  Are these NAs on the 'date' column or in 'id' column?  Do you want to remove the NAs rows before proceeding with this?